# Need to regain access to old account - no response to e-mail, and recovery form not working

Tags: support, accounts, merge-accounts

I've lost access to an old account that I *really* want back. I do not remember *which* e-mail address that I used *at the time of registering*, however, I can give you a list of about a hundred e-mails that I've owned since I first started using the internet - so one of them is bound to be the one. I have previously e-mailed support, but did not get a response from anybody. I have also filled out the form to recover my account, but no response there either.

I remember other information provided when signing up like name/DOB, location, etc. How can I regain control of my old account? I really, *really* want it back.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: How long ago did you email the team? They get a lot of emails, and it sometimes can take a few days to process.

Comment: @BradLarson Late last year, and then again a couple months ago. I even forgot I emailed them at all until lastnight when I dreamt that I regained access to the old account.

Comment: Ok, I've filled out the Merge and Lost Password forms in the Help Center pages, so hopefully somebody can help me out with this. :)

Comment: Ok, so it's been a few days since I sent that email. I hope they've received it. I haven't got a response yet.